# MySQL; List from different categories

Tags: mysql, sql, categories

Let's say I've the following table called `test`:

[image]

I need to SELECT to get the following:

[image]

Does anybody know how to do that with SQL?

Comment: "Does anybody know how to do that with SQL?" yes

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: See that result. That's normalised. That's what your table should look like to begin with.

Comment: Oh, and it's 'plum'

Comment: @Strawberry I'll simply change it to `Strawberry`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
select category,
    item
from test
where category is not null

union all

select category2 as category,
    item
from test
where category2 is not null
order by item
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/AXRG44703)

Comment: Thanks, seems to work. But, how can I `ORDER BY`? `SELECT * FROM ([your code]) ORDER BY item` doesn't work. I'm getting: `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`.

Comment: @David - Yes. Updated the answer too.